# Log4net error in Crystal reports on Windows Azure Web App Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, azure, crystal-reports

I've created a web application in Asp.net Webforms with Crystal reports 13 in VS2015.I deployed it to Windows Azure Web App.Everything works fine except when i try to show report it shows error like:

**Server Error in '/' Application.**

**Could not load file or assembly 'log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.**

The Screenshot [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQVNx.png)

i searched several threads regarding this.But all solutions are related to azure vm or cloud service. I've found nothing on Web App Service. Anyone have any idea how to solve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, I followed [how-to-create-crystal-reports-in-asp-net-webforms](http://tektutorialshub.com/how-to-create-crystal-reports-in-asp-net-webforms/) to build my web application in Asp.net WebForms with Crystal reports on my side and I could reproduce your issue when deploying it to an Azure Web App.

When adding a Crystal Report to the ASP.NET WebForm project, we could find the references to the following Crystal Report Namespace are added to our project.

[image]

Note: `CrystalDecisions.Web.dll` references the log4net which is installed as an assembly into the Global Assembly Cache when you installing the CR runtimes.

[image]

Meanwhile, I tried to export the `log4net.dll` from GAC and reference it to my project directly. But it couldn't work well as expected.

Upon my testing, I assumed that Azure Web App couldn't meet your requirement since you couldn't connect remotely to your web app and install the CR runtimes. You could use Cloud Service or Azure VM instead.

Comment: I just checked out [azure-feedback-forum](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-websites/suggestions/6771442-crystal-reports-in-azure-websites) ,though it was a old post but i think still now they haven't add ability to host CR in Web App. Thanks for your help

Comment: Glad to hear that. If you have any concerns about CR on Azure, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: can you help me regarding CR on Azure vm ? i'm totally new in azure vm

Comment: You could follow this [tutorial](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-windows-hero-tutorial/) to create your VM in the Azure Portal. Also, you could follow this [tutorial](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-windows-classic-web-app-visual-studio/) to create a VM for your web app with VS. After you created the VM, you could remote to your VM and follow this [tutorial](http://tektutorialshub.com/how-to-download-and-install-crystal-report-runtime/) to install Crystal Report Runtime.